# How do i automatically hit a submit button in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a ScanField. In this field i'm scanning a barcode. After that i'm cutting the last four character of the bardcode-string and give it to the hiddenField. And from that hidden field when i click on the search button i pass it to the php site via ajax.

for example: i'm scanning a barcode: `TWRG000000009102` in the hiddenfield shows `9102` and after that im passing the value to ajax.

Everthing works fine but i would like to do it automatically. When the hidden inputField was filled it should fire an event and pass the value to ajax.

my code:

```
    <label for="myType">
        <select id="myType" name="myType" size="5">
            <option value="01">B&C</option>
            <option value="02">James Nicholson</option>
            <option value="F.O.L">Fruit Of The Loom</option>
            <option value="TeeJays">TeeJays</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <br>
    <label for="hiddenField">hiddenField:</label>
    <input type="text" name="hiddenField" style="width:300px"><br>
    <label for="myScan">Scanfield:</label>

    <input type="text" name="myScan" style="width:300px" autofocus>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=myScan]').on('keypress', function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var scanField = $(this).val();
            console.log(scanField);
            var lastFour = scanField.substr(scanField.length - 4);
            $('input[name=hiddenField]').val(lastFour);
        }
    });

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var postForm = {
            'myType' : $('#myType').val(),
            'myScan' : $('input[name=hiddenField]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: postForm,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here the html example: https://jsfiddle.net/froouf9f/

Comment: Why not $('button').click()?

Comment: i need a cold shower right now ! thanks for help now it's working !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you save value to hidden field, you can trigger button click event using:

```
$("button").trigger("click");
```

Try this:

```
$('input[name=myScan]').on('keypress', function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var scanField = $(this).val();
            console.log(scanField);
            var lastFour = scanField.substr(scanField.length - 4);
            $('input[name=hiddenField]').val(lastFour);
            $("button").trigger("click");
        }
    });
```